# Recursion Error(Jupyter Notebook/Google Colab)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm creating a map that contains points that features a description of the location. I get a Recursion Error when I try to run my code. "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"

Here is my code:

```py
for i in range(10):
    lat = map_data['LATLNG'].iloc[i][0]
    long = map_data['LATLNG'].iloc[i][1]
    location=map_data['address'].iloc[i]

    if map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i] > 150:
        color = 'red'
    elif map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i] >= 100:
        color = 'orange'
    elif map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i] < 100:
        color = 'blue'
    
    popup_text = """
                Location: {}<br>
                Peace Disruptions : {}<br>"""
    popup_text = popup_text.format(
                               location, 
                               map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i]
                             )

    folium.Marker(
        location = [lat, long],
        popup= popup_text,
        icon = folium.Icon(color= color)
    ).add_to(stl_crime_street)
```

Anyone know how to fix this error?

[image: Sample of the database that I'm using]

edit: Traceback call

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-e1777bcd5945> in <module>()
     17                                map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i]
     18                                )
---> 19     folium.Marker(location = [lat, long], popup= popup_text,icon=folium.Icon(color= color)).add_to(stl_crime_street)


   69     for i in container:
     70         if _is_sized_iterable(i):
---> 71             for j in _flatten(i):
     72                 yield j
     73         else:

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback output for your error.  You can [edit] your question.

Comment: I added the code to the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Import sys and set the maximum recursion depth to something higher.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500) # for example 1500
```

However there doesn't seem to be any recursion in your code. So I'm wondering how you got the error.